# Difference between $\forall xp(x) \vee \forall xq(x)$ and $\forall x(p(x) \vee q(x))$ in english?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm studying logic and I was reading about the distributive property of the universal quantifier, and this got me pretty confused.

Let $p(x)$ mean "eats cake" and $q(x)$ mean "eats ice cream"

Saying everyone eats cake or ice cream would be:
$$\forall x( p(x) \vee q(x) )$$

Saying everyone eats cake or everyone eats ice cream would be:
$$\forall xp(x) \vee \forall xq(x)$$

but what is the difference between these two sentences? I think I thought about it for too long and I'm making things over-complicated but I don't really get it.

If I go to a restaurant and they tell me "here everyone eats cake or everyone eats ice cream" this means that everyone in that restaurant, at the same time/day, eats ice cream or cake. If instead they told me "here everyone eats cake or ice cream" does it mean that everyone eats cake or ice cream and nothing else but maybe some people are having some cake and some people are eating some ice cream? Is that the difference?

Comment: "Either Every (natural) number is Even or Every (natural) number is Odd" versus "Every (natural) number is Either Even or Odd".

Comment: Is that the difference? Yes

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but isn't the "or" an "inclusive or"? if yes, that should not exclude the fact that a number is both even and odd, or not?

Comment: There is no number that is both even and odd... The above example means that "Every number is Even" is False and "Every number is Odd" is False; thus, their disjunction is False. The other statement, instead, is True. Conclusion; the example show what is the difference.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's the difference.

To illustrate, say we have a model with three people, Paul, Bob and Alice, such that:

- Paul eats cake, but no ice cream
- Bob eats cake and ice cream
- Alice eats ice cream, but no cake

Form this we can conclude:

- Paul eats cake or ice cream
- Bob eats cake or ice cream
- Alice eats cake or ice cream
- So everyone eats either cake or ice cream.

But:

- Paul doesn't eat ice cream
- So not everyone eats ice cream
- Alice doesn't eat cake
- So not everyone eats cake
- Since neither everyone eats cake nor everyone eats ice cream, it is not the case that everyone eats cake or everyone eats ice cream.

$\forall x (p(x) \lor q(x))$ is true, but $\forall x p(x) \lor \forall x q(x)$ is not, so the two can not be logically equivalent.

Comment: and in the first case, if paul bob and alice all had cake i could still say "everyone eats either cake or ice cream" right?

Comment: @cekami7844 Yes.

Comment: so that means that the implication: $$∀x(p(x) ∨ q(x)) →  (∀xp(x) ∨ ∀xq(x))$$ is not valid only because of the case in which p(x) and q(x) happen at the same time right? <br>

For example, "if everything is red or yellow, then everything is red or everything is yellow"<br>

if everything is red or everything is yellow the antecedent and the consequent are both true.<br>

if something is red and everything else is yellow, then the antecedent is true BUT the consequent is yellow.<br>

Correct? (thank you so much for your answers by the way)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "at the same time" -- if you mean cases where both $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are true for some $x$, such as for Bob, that's not a problem. What you are right about is that the implication is not valid, because there are counter examples like the ice cream vs. cake eating one, where the antecedent $\forall x (p(x) \lor q(x))$ is true but the consequent $\forall x p(x) \lor \forall x q(x)$ is false. However, the other direction of the implication does hold: $\forall x p(x) \lor \forall x q(x) \to \forall x (p(x) \lor q(x))$ is valid.

Comment: And of course, there may be specific interpretations where both the antecedent $\forall x (p(x) \lor q(x))$ and the consequent $\forall x p(x) \lor \forall x q(x)$ happen to be true -- but as long as there is at least one counter example, such as the one in this answer, this is enough to show that the implication is not valid (= universally true).

Comment: in my discrete mathematics , course we 've learned that : $\exists x(p(x) \lor q(x) )\equivs \exists xp(x) \lor \exists xq(x)$ as "the law of distirbution of quantifiers" .

Comment: @brucebanner Yes, that's correct. But the same does not hold for the universal quantifier.